# SSH connection under UDP?

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, firewall, udp

Is there a way to establish a SSH connection over UDP?

I'm running behind a "filter all inbound TCP traffic" firewall so I cannot utilize a SSH tunnel properly.

I have set up over at my brothers that I have control over (SSH). I want to connect to it from behind the firewall to somehow port forward to the MySQL and Redis databases I have on my servers behind the firewall.

Comment: OpenVPN typically runs over UDP.  If you can establish an OpenVPN connection, you could `ssh` over that, although then you should also be able to directly access your MySQL and REDIS without using `ssh` as another transport tunnel layer.

Comment: Assuming here that you _have_ confirmed UDP is not firewalled.

Comment: What exactly is, from your perspective, *behind* the firewall? You? Or the SSH server host? Why do you think it wouldn't block UDP? Is the firewall a NAT router?

Comment: Just connecting to a VPN does not work as I'm sure you need to port forward something to the VPN network and back.
UDP comes back as open by nmap and I can use OpenVPN over UDP by specifying any random UDP port range.
From my perspective, I am behind the firewall and so is the server I want to port forward to. I'm not really sure what type of firewall it is, but I know there are 3 routes from the external point to my internal router, so it could be anything really. I do know for sure UDP works though.

Comment: @B.Garrison: "Just connecting to a VPN does not work as I'm sure you need to port forward something".  No, if you have a VPN connection *between your local network and the remote network*, there is no need for any port-forwarding.

Answer (score 2):

The [Mobile Shell](https://mosh.org/) (Mosh).

**[Prerequisites of the server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosh_(software)#Prerequisites_on_the_server)**

> The major drawback of mosh is that it requires the server to fulfill
>   additional prerequisites which are not needed by ssh itself. **Due to
>   its design, mosh needs the server to allow direct connections via
>   UDP.** Servers not fulfilling these prerequisites cannot be used by
>   mosh. **Examples of such systems include servers behind firewalls which
>   restrict connections to the ssh-port via TCP.** Also problematic are
>   servers which are only indirectly reachable. The latter is usually
>   accommodated by ssh via the 'ProxyCommand' option, but this is not
>   supported by mosh.

**One port per connection.**

> By **default**, the server tries to allocate the first free UDP port in
>   the range 60000-61000, per connection. This dynamic port allocation is
>   considered an extra burden and risk for firewall maintenance. A
>   significant part of the firewall-filtering happens through connection
>   tracking, so called stateful filtering, this is based on the SYN/ACK
>   flags in TCP segments, UDP packets don't have such flags.

**Other things.**

- No IPv6 roaming support.
- Scrollback is not supported in the current release of mosh, and when using it in a terminal emulator with scrollbars they disappear.
- Lack of SSH-Agent forwarding.
- Lack of X-11 forwarding.

For more see [SSH vs Mosh](http://linuxpitstop.com/ssh-vs-mosh/).

Comment: Mosh would solve SSH access, but I still need my databases forwarded and some other services too. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Although mosh is cool, it requires both tcp and udp. It first connects via regular ssh, then drops to udp.

Comment: Even for a simple interactive remote shell, Mosh has the drawback that [it does not support the alternate screen](https://github.com/mobile-shell/mosh/issues/843), partly due to the fact that it emulates a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Check out hscp, which isn't exactly what you're looking for but may have some of the features you want. UDP-based SCP, plus I think some SSH basics.  https://ccportal.ims.ac.jp/en/software/hscp